# How to get same key multiple times from json response?

Tags: json, ruby, httparty

I need to get all the "customer" keys from following response

[
    {
        "customer": "Gary South",
        "type": "Dealer",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "vehicles": "CAR ",
                "type": "SUV"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer": "William TUSK",
        "type": "Reseller",
        "addresses": [
            {
               "vehicles": "CAR ",
                "type": "SUV"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer": "Lynn Baker",
        "type": "Dealer",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "vehicles": "VANS",
                "type": "BUSINESS"
            }
        ]
    }
   ]

I tried the following code but it only gets first 'name' key value.

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
result.each do |item|
assert_equal @customerNames, item['customer']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `end` the `do` statement, you basically need to loop through all the items and then compare the list of names.

```
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
names = []
data.each do |item|
  names.push(item['name'])
end
puts names
```

Output:

```
Gary South
William TUSK
Lynn Baker
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
names = data.map { |elem| elem['name'] } 
#=> ["Gary South", "William TUSK", "Lynn Baker"]

assert_equal @names, names
```